# Fix XBMC CPU usage?

Tags: xbmc

I am trying to use XBMC to play a Blu Ray.  It worked fine yesterday but today it makes my computer freeze.  I think it is CPU related so thought id try this: http://thepcspy.com/read/how-fix-idle-100-cpu-issue-xbmc/

I'm not seeing advancedsettings.xml however.  Do you have any suggestions on how to get Blu Ray playback working in Ubuntu?

Comment: advancedsettings.xml does not exist by default, you need to create it. Check xbmc.log to make sure that it gets loaded at startup.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods out there that can be used to play a BluRay disc under Linux. Most are pretty painful and make buying a BluRay player and sitting it next to your monitor look like a viable solution.

VLC is a universal video player - it plays just about everything except DLNA streams. It's also a very popular player. Installation:

To do so Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

If you require further information or reading [See this site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/BluRayAndHDDVD)

Comment: VLC can't play blu rays

Comment: Look at this http://vlc-bluray.whoknowsmy.name/